# `root_scope` does not live long enough

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and I'm having some issues that I can't seem to figure out on my own.

The code:

```rust
struct Value;

enum Val<'a> {
    Null,
    String(&'a str),
    Symbol(&'a str),
    Builtin(Box<dyn Fn(Vec<&Val>) -> Val<'a>>),
    Function(Vec<&'a str>, &'a ()),
}

struct Scope<'a> {
    idents: std::collections::HashMap<&'a str, Val<'a>>,
    parent: Option<&'a Scope<'a>>,
}

fn apply<'a>(scope: &'a Scope<'a>) -> Val<'a> {
    let mut _new_scope = Scope{
        idents: std::collections::HashMap::new(),
        parent: Some(scope),
    };
    Val::Null
}

fn eval<'a>(_val: &'a Value, scope: &'a Scope<'a>) -> Val<'a> {
    apply(scope);
    Val::Null
}

fn main() {
    let v = Value;
    
    let root_scope = Scope {
        idents: std::collections::HashMap::new(),
        parent: None,
    };

    let _ = eval(&v, &root_scope);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `root_scope` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:37:22
   |
37 |     let _ = eval(&v, &root_scope);
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
38 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `root_scope` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `root_scope` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `Scope<'_>`
```

I've tried removing the explicit lifetime on `scope` in `eval`, `apply`, and the `Scope` struct, but then I get this error:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/main.rs:13:20
   |
13 |     parent: Option<&Scope<'a>>,
   |                    ^ expected named lifetime parameter
   |
help: consider using the `'a` lifetime
   |
13 |     parent: Option<&'a Scope<'a>>,
   |                    ^^^
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to force your `Builtin`s values return value to live in `'a` ? otherwise it will work with arbitrary lifetimes (`Builtin(Box<dyn for<'b> Fn(Vec<&'b Val>) -> Val<'b>>)`) , [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3237ac4dd3add25dfcce6c6e65e26c25)

Comment: @ÖmerErden thanks. I'll try to use this.